# Vue router not rendering component on url change

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vite

I am using vue router in my vite project to render the correct page/component based on the url. I am first using router-link to change the url, then specifying the page that should be rendered on that url. The url is changing but the page remains the same. I am not quite sure what I am doing wrong here

App.vue:

```html
<template>
  <Login />
</template>
```

Login.vue:

```html
<template>
  <div class="w-64">
    <p class="text-3xl mb-4">Login</p>
    <div class="flex flex-col bg-white p-4 rounded border border-grey text-left">
      <p class="mb-2">Username:</p>
      <input type="text" class="border border-black rounded p-1">
      <p class="mb-2">Password:</p>
      <input type="password" class="border border-black rounded p-1">
    </div>
    <div class="bg-[#99C8C2] w-1/2 rounded p-2 mx-auto mt-4 hover:opacity-70" @click="temp">
        Login
    </div>
    <p> Dont have an Account ?</p>
    <router-link to="/signup">
          Sign Up
    </router-link>
  </div>
</template>
```

router.js:

```js
import { createRouter, createWebHistory, createWebHashHistory } from 'vue-router';
import App from './App.vue';
import SignUp from './Pages/SignUp.vue'

const routes = [
  { path: '/',name: 'Main Page', component: App },
  { path: '/signup', component: SignUp }
];

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(),
  routes
});

export default router;
```

main.js:

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import './assets/style.css'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'


const app = createApp(App);
app.use(router);
app.mount('#app');
```

Comment: Please share app.vue and main.js

Comment: I already have included my app.vue, which is just me rendering another component called Login in the template. I have added the main.js now

Answer (score 0):

You should add `router-view` component inside App.vue :

```html
<template>
  <router-view></router-view>
</template>
```

Comment: should I place my login component inside router-view? I added it in but it still doesnt render the correct component on url change

Comment: Do not place it inside.  `<router-view />` is a placeholder component, and is necessary for vue-router to work.  Whatever route is currently being matched, that route's component (defined in router.js) will replace `<router-view />` in the DOM.  Likely you should give Login it's own route.